# issue trying to get the atributes from dll classes using a wcf that communicates with a silverlight application

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf, silverlight, dll

I use a dll that has classes for common task in c#. in that dll i have a class called clResultadoOperacionBD that i used to check if a datarow in a database was inserted or updated correctly having attributes like Id, Message , Operation Result, etc.

here are the atribbutes:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Id Registro tipo entero
    /// </summary>
    public int Id32 { get { return _id_32; } }
    /// <summary>
    /// Id Registro tipo Long
    /// </summary>
    public long Id64 { get { return _id_64; } }
    /// <summary>
    /// Bool que indica si la operación es exitosa o no
    /// </summary>
    public bool Resultado { get { return _resultado; } }
    /// <summary>
    /// Indica el mensaje del resultado de una operación
    /// </summary>
    public string Mensaje { get { return _mensaje; } }
```

i have used this class several times and its ok.

I created a class library in c# using this dll for a requirement.

Then i created a silverlight project in VB.net and to communicate to the DB i use a wcf in the web project:

```
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.ServiceModel.Activation
Imports ClasesBase
Imports Entities

<ServiceContract(Namespace:="")>
<SilverLightFaultBehavior()>
<AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode:=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)>
Public Class wcf_comentario

    <OperationContract()>
    Public Function InsertaComentario(ByVal nombre As String, comentario As String, correo As String) As clResultadoOperacionBD
        Using c As Comentario = New Comentario With {.Id = 0, .Nombre = nombre, .Comentary = comentario, .Correo = correo}
            Return Repositories.ComentarioRepo.InsertaComentario(c)
        End Using
    End Function

End Class
```

After that i added the service reference in the silverlight project and my issue is that when i cannot used the object attributes in the completed event args of the wcf, thought the row was inserted in the database correctly.

```
Private Sub insercion_completed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Prueba.InsertaComentarioCompletedEventArgs) Handles comentario_wcf.InsertaComentarioCompleted
    lblResultado.Text = e.Result.GetType().Name

    indicador.IsBusy = False

    txtComentario.Text = ""
    txtCorreo.Text = ""
    txtNombre.Text = ""
End Sub
```

the intellisence only show me the GetType Attribute and i want to know the way to use the attributes of that class.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to reach attribures on Result property with reflection?

Comment: correct, iwant to reach the attributes of that class, i noticed that if i create a class inside the project that holds the silverlight app its ok(in the e.Result it shows the attributes) but i dont want to duplicate the code, is it possible in silverlight to use the classes from .net dll´s

Comment: I don't know any limitations about attrbiutes when using reflection in silverlight, so did you try e.Result.GetType().GetCustomAttributes() as a list? Are you sure you want to get attributes or properties?

Comment: the properties of the class, when i create the object i initialize it with an Id, if is higher than 0 is set a the variable Resultado(boolean) as true, so in that variable i cannot find that attribute of the object sended in the wcf, thought it get the type im unnable to get the properties of that object

Comment: I read there are some restrinctions in silverlight with the properties of the object for security purposes, if i would have use attributes instead of properties it would´ve been visible